# React 0.18 causes Module error

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I'm getting the following error when trying to get a Module working after updating to React Native 0.18:

> com.lwansbrough.RCTCamera.RCTCameraViewManager cannot be cast to
>   com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewGroupmanager

What causes this type of error, and how can it be resolved?

Here is the code for RCTCameraViewManager:

```
package com.lwansbrough.RCTCamera;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.*;

public class RCTCameraViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<RCTCameraView> {
    private static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCTCameraView";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    public RCTCameraView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
        return new RCTCameraView(context);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "aspect")
    public void setAspect(RCTCameraView view, int aspect) {
        view.setAspect(aspect);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "captureMode")
    public void setCaptureMode(RCTCameraView view, int captureMode) {
        // TODO - implement video mode
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "captureTarget")
    public void setCaptureTarget(RCTCameraView view, int captureTarget) {
        // No reason to handle this props value here since it's passed again to the RCTCameraModule capture method
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "type")
    public void setType(RCTCameraView view, int type) {
        view.setCameraType(type);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "torchMode")
    public void setTorchMode(RCTCameraView view, int torchMode) {
        view.setTorchMode(torchMode);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "flashMode")
    public void setFlashMode(RCTCameraView view, int flashMode) {
        view.setFlashMode(flashMode);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "orientation")
    public void setOrientation(RCTCameraView view, int orientation) {
        view.setOrientation(orientation);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "captureAudio")
    public void setCaptureAudio(RCTCameraView view, boolean captureAudio) {
        // TODO - implement video mode
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also got this error, my solution was to change the

```
public class RCTCameraViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<RCTCameraView>
```

to

```
public class RCTCameraViewManager extends ViewGroupManager<RCTCameraView>
```